# How to use libavl?

Tags: c, sorting, binary-search-tree, gnu

I'm trying to use GNU `libavl` (http://adtinfo.org/) for one of my academic projects. I need a simple enough tutorial on how to use the BST(Binary search tree) implementation provided by the library. What I need to do is sort a (key,value) pair(about 30000 strings and there  frequencies) using a BST according to the value. Although the library is well documented, it doesn't give any straight foreword answer to my question and I don't have the time to read trough all the documentation and test code. I would like to know if there is much faster way to do the sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    tree *avl_tree = NULL;
    struct data tmp;
    unsigned result;

    (void) argc;
    (void) argv;

    // Initialize a new tree with our three previously defined
    // functions to store data structure.
    avl_tree = init_dictionnary(data_cmp, data_print, data_delete, data_copy);

    tmp.key = 42;
    tmp.value = 4242;

    // Add element {42, 4242} in our tree.
    result = insert_elmt(avl_tree, &tmp, sizeof(struct data));
```

Comment: @Madushan Did you even look at the example?  Not only does it only contain only a single example (using AVL trees only, not any of the other kinds of binary trees offered by GNU libavl) but I can't even tell how this github project is even related to the GNU project!

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is wrong since it points to a different library instead of GNU libavl. Also it doesn't answer the original inquiry.

> I need a simple enough tutorial

I'm not aware about any tutorials for this library. You also say that

> I don't have the time to read trough all the documentation and test code.

But while there is no better option I think reading tests is the best possible recommendation for people who are interested in understanding GNU libavl. Also the accepted answer is even further by relevance from what I'm about to write.

GNU libavl contains tests which can be read as usage examples. But since the library is written in TexiWEB language, in order to get the C source code you have to compile the original source first.

Clone the source code:

```
$ git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/avl.git
```

Then inside the `avl` directory run:

```
$ make programs
```

After the compilation you'll see the C source code and compiled binaries.

Now you can read the tests and find out from there how to use the library. Test sources have `-test.c` suffix. For example tests for AVL trees are in the `avl-test.c` file.

Also note, that GNU libavl is not intended to be used as a shared library so you'll have to include the C source files to your project.